# move matching files in folder if they match a specific destination folder name

Tags: bash

I can not figure out how to move files to a folder if the match part of the name of the folder.

For example, if I have 4 files that the below bash will use a specific file extension and create a folder for:

**Bash**

```
for f in /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/2-19-2016/*.bam
do
   [ -d "$f" ] && continue
   base=${f%.*}
   mkdir -p "$base"
   mv "$f" "$base/"
done
```

Before the `bash` is run:

```
IonXpress_001.bam
IonXpress_002.bam
IonXpress_003.bam
IonXpress_007.bam
```

After the `bash` is run

4 folders are created with each `.bam` inside of it:

```
 `Folder`            `File`
IonXpress_001 >>> IonXpress_001.bam
IonXpress_002 >>> IonXpress_002.bam
IonXpress_003 >>> IonXpress_003.bam
IonXpress_007 >>> IonXpress_007.bam
```

In the `folder` there is a directory named `test` that has 4 files in it:

```
 IonXpress_001_newheader_all_IDT.meterics
 IonXpress_002_newheader_all_IDT.meterics
 IonXpress_003_newheader_all_IDT.meterics
 IonXpress_007_newheader_all_IDT.meterics
```

I am trying to move the `file` in the `test folder` that matches the beginning string into the main folder.  The `test folder` is also moved as a subdirectory with the `file` in it.  I apologize for the lenghty post just trying to provide all the details.  Thank you :).

**desired result**

```
   `Folder`            `File`           `folder`
IonXpress_001 >>> IonXpress_001.bam   >>> test >>> IonXpress_001_newheader_all_IDT.meterics
IonXpress_002 >>> IonXpress_002.bam   >>> test >>> IonXpress_002_newheader_all_IDT.meterics
IonXpress_003 >>> IonXpress_003.bam   >>> test >>> IonXpress_003_newheader_all_IDT.meterics   
IonXpress_007 >>> IonXpress_007.bam   >>> test >>> IonXpress_007_newheader_all_IDT.meterics
```

**edit**

```
 for f in /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/2-19-2016/*.bam
do
 base="${f%.*}"
 mkdir -p "$base"; mkdir -p "$base/"(picard,fastqc,bedtools,30x}
 mv "$f" "$base/"
 mv "picard/fastqc/bedtools/30x/$f"* "$base/picard/fastqc/bedtools/30x"
done

 `Folder`            `File`           `folder`
IonXpress_001 >>> IonXpress_001.bam   >>> picard/fastqc/bedtools/30x >>> IonXpress_001_newheader_all_IDT.meterics
IonXpress_002 >>> IonXpress_002.bam   >>> picard/fastqc/bedtools/30x >>> IonXpress_002_newheader_all_IDT.meterics
IonXpress_003 >>> IonXpress_003.bam   >>> picard/fastqc/bedtools/30x >>> IonXpress_003_newheader_all_IDT.meterics   
IonXpress_007 >>> IonXpress_007.bam   >>> picard/fastqc/bedtools/30x >>> IonXpress_007_newheader_all_IDT.meterics
```

Comment: What is full path of `test` folder now?

Comment: @anubhava the full path is `/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/2-19-2016/test`.... thank you :).

Comment: Can you post the full paths of everything in the question, i don't really understand which files/folders are going where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your existing script like this:

```
sub='picard/fastqc/bedtools/30x'

for f in /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/2-19-2016/*.bam
do
   base="${f%.*}"
   mkdir -p {"$base","$base/$sub"}

   mv "$f" "$base/"
   mv "$sub/$f"* "$base/$sub/"
done
```

`mkdir -p` exits silently if destination directory already exists.

Comment: if there are multiple subfolders besides test (test,name,count,result,less), all in the same path, can all off those be used? `mkdir -p {"$base","$base/test/name/count/result/less"} or is there a better way?  Thank you :).

Comment: Use: `mkdir -p "$base"; mkdir -p "$base/"(test,name,count,result,less}`

Comment: I added an edit with the `bash` but I get `mv: cannot stat ‘picard/fastqc/bedtools/30x/*’: No such file or directory`.... thank you :).

Comment: I will put the directory structure in the edit, but it is basically this '/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/2-19-2016/test` but the `test is multiple sub-directories` .  Thank you :)

Comment: That creates the sub-directories `picard then fastqc is a sub directory then bedtools is a subdirectory, then 30x is a sub directory` and doesn't move the files.... thank you for all your help :).

Comment: That's what your question shows here `picard/fastqc/bedtools/30x >>>`

Comment: It is hard to explain without being able to attach screenshots, but each of the sub-directories has files.  Thank you for your help I will try using some of the code examples and re-post if I get stuck Thank you :).